# Physx Dynamic Actor Motion

Tags: physx

I have a dynamic spheres. How to enter it in motion? To then be able to bounce back from obstacles. Gravity disabled.
Do Not I use after x ++ y ++ in 3d and in the shape of a sphere actor.

Answer (score 0):

To set a dynamic actor in motion. Use addForce function of that actor.

To disable gravity for an actor, use raiseBodyFlag (NX_BF_DISABLE_GRAVITY) on that actor.

Comment: @user3756381 If my answer worked for you, please accept it. :) And for the other question you asked about PhysX too :)